# Is there a web service I can use to receive SOAP requests and send REST requests

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, wsdl

I wish to create a one way integration between a system that can only send SOAP requests and a system that can only respond to REST requests.  I know very little about web services as it is not my specialty.  But the source system can be configured to send a SOAP request to any WSDL and the 'destination' system has a REST API and provides me with a simple URL to which I can send requests to 'trigger' an event.
I would have thought it would be simple to find some web service that can receive the SOAP requests from the source system, which would be a simple request to send a REST request to the destination system.
Like some sort of intermediary, not actually converting the requests directly but forming a similar function.  Is there anything that can do this?

Comment: Are you using any kind of integration product like BizTalk or Websphere? Or are you going to be writing the integration yourself?

Comment: We're not using any integration product and in fact, I don't even know what these are.  This product sending the SOAP requests has only a limited life here and I have limited time and ability to write a web service integration.  We have a person who can easily send any request to a WSDL and on the other side, I can easily work out the URL for the REST API.  I want to install or buy a product that will just link the two together, if possible.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like the "product" you are going to need is some time from a developer. You're going to need to get a web service written and hosted on your side, which can then make a call out to your REST endpoint on receipt of a request.